# POST 400 Bad request

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, axios

I am new to django and reactjs and I am trying to POST request using axios but I am unable to send data. I am getting console error

POST http://localhost:8000/api/todos/ 400 (Bad Request)

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",
  "secure": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.5.0",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is my App.js where i am using axios

```
 refreshList = () => {
        axios
        //   .get("/api/todos/", {
        //     headers: {
        //         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        //     }
        // })
          .get("http://localhost:8000/api/todos/", { headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                }
            })
          .then(res => this.setState({ todoList: res.data }))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };
```

Comment: The error is likely coming from your python script. Not seeing your python script do you log your errors to see what the error could be on the server side?

Comment: Open your browser's dev tool box, look at the network tab, refresh the request and look at the response's content. You will have a meaningful error message that will help you to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: You can check catch errors is your browser's network tab

Answer (score 0):

If you console log the response status it should give you a more detailed description of the error.

Example:

```
if(response) {
console.log(response.status)
}
```